# Run @AfterSuite without running any test

Tags: selenium, testng

I am running selenium testng tests `parallely` by running:
`mvn test -Dtest="test-x"` on `different machines` for each of the tests.

I am also using @AfterSuite and @BeforeSuite. Problem is that these methods are being run on each machine. I don't want that.

What I want is:

- @BeforeSuite runs on a separate machine only once.

  when this completes
- Run all the tests parallely on different machines.

  when all of these tests completes
- @AfterSuite is run on a separate machine only once.

Machines on which @AfterSuite and @BeforeSuite are run should not run any tests. And, machines on which tests run, should not run these hooks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Then write that code(which is under `BeforeSuite` and `AfterSuite` ) as separate tests and use the priority to execute those tests in the beginning and at the end.

Comment: @NandanA priority won't work here as I am running these individual tests as different processes on different machines parallely. There is no IPC happening, all processes are isolated. Semantically also, running AfterSuite  as a test does not seem correct. Can't I just run `@AfterSuite` only, without running any test?

Comment: Do you want all your agents which run independently to somehow synchronize to decide who should take the responsibility and execute `@AfterSuite`?

Comment: @AlexeyR. No,
I want that when all tests complete, I should be able to run @AfterSuite without running any test. 
Like adding any flags to the command:
`mvn test -DafterSuite=true` which will only run the @AfterSuite and nothing else.